# Process, How to use Outputstream to send the message two times

Tags: java

This is my code:

```
Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("something command"); 

String s;

JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setSize(600, 400);
JTextField A = new JTextField();
A.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String s = A.getText();
    System.out.println("I send a text: " + s);
    try{
         p.getOutputStream().write(s.getBytes());
         p.getOutputStream().close();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    A.setText("");
}    
});
frame.add(A);
frame.setVisible(true);


// Read command standard input
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
   System.out.println(s);
}
```

I want to use p.getOutputStream() to send the message two times, but the problem is I need to close the OutputStream to send. I can't send again because it have been closd. Can I reconnect the OutputStream or no need to close the OutputStream?

Thx:)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling `close()`, you can call [`flush()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#flush--) which *flushes this output stream and forces any buffered output bytes to be written out.* Then you can `close()`, after you've written your messages the desired number of times.